# Format Specifier for arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, formatting

I'm returning a few arrays, (a, b, and c) in a function which I want to write out into a text file for which I am currently using numpy.savetxt.

When I print each one separtely, they are formatted as such.

```
(4, 6)
[[1 2]
 [2 3]
 [3 4]
 [4 1]
 [1 3]
 [2 4]]
[ 3.  1.  1.]
```

I'm currently using

```
numpy.savetxt('text.txt', (a,b,c) , fmt='%s')
```

to save it to a text file but I do not know the format specifiers to be able to save it in the following format

```
4
6
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 1
1 3
2 4
3 1 1
```

Comment: I would open the file for write, and do a separate `savetxt` for each  array.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the arrays are printed in that manner is because they're of different shapes. You might want to either reshape them or use the [np.savez](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html) method to have each array saved a separate file, to retain its structure.